# I try to reduce a MPEG-4 video's bitrate with GPU acceleration，but something is wrong

Tags: ffmpeg

> ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v
> mpeg4_cuvid -i "F:\dataset\celeb-df-v1\Celeb-real\id0_0002.mp4"
> -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 574k -y "F:\dataset\celeb-df-v1\compress\id0_0002.mp4"

It keeps reporting errors like:

> Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter
> 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0' Error reinitializing
> filters! Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not
> implemented Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0

Here is my video info

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'F:\dataset\celeb-df-v1\\Celeb-real\id0_0002.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.3.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1148 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 942x500 [SAR 1:1 DAR 471:250], 1146 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (mpeg4_cuvid) -> mpeg4 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

Comment: You only need to specify the codec once. `-vcodec mpeg4` is at odds with `-c:v mpeg4_cuvid`. Try removing `-vcodec mpeg4`. See https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2017-February/035335.html